# Bootstrap Carousel with Meteor

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm having a problem with my code. I'm new in learning Meteor. I can't fix it for several hours already. I included a carousel in my practice site and it is not working the way it is supposed to be, all the pictures were just appearing. I copy pasted the carousel template from bootstrap's website and stored it inside template tag.

```html
<template name="Carousel">
  <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

<ol class="carousel-indicators">
  <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
  <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ol>

  
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
  <div class="item active">
    <img src="/images/1.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="item active">
    <img src="/images/2.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="item active">
    <img src="/images/3.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Controls -->
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
  </div>
</template>
```

This is my homelayout where I call the carousel's template

```html
<template name="HomeLayout">
    {{> yield "Navigation"}}
    {{> yield "Carousel"}}  
</template>
```

And this is my route

```js
Router.route('/', function () {
  this.layout('HomeLayout');
  this.render('Navigation', {to: 'Navigation'});
  this.render('Carousel', {to: 'Carousel'});
});
```

In addition, can I also get tips/feedback with regards to the proper coding of page routing in Meteor?

All your help is greatly appreciated. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, 
after a couple of minutes, I found the error. I accidentally added the 'active' class in each of the item. 
I don't know whether to laugh or cry. xD
Maybe I just need some sleep.